# Package kinesis.clientlibrary.exceptions does not exist in Java Import Statements

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, maven, build, amazon-kinesis

Hello – I’m trying to import the AWS Kinesis Client library (https://github.com/awslabs/amazon-kinesis-client) in Java & Netbeans, and am getting an error message in the import section.

Package com.amazonaws.services.kinesis.clientlibrary.exceptions does not exist.  Snapshot

[image]

Other com.amazonaws.services dependencies pull in just fine – just not kinesis.clientlibrary.

I downloaded the AWS Kinesis Library java code from github and built it using Maven.  For sake of troubleshooting I placed the following jar files in a folder:

kinesis-2.0.6.jar

utils-2.0.6.jar

annotations-2.0.6.jar

apache-client-2.0.6.jar

apache-client-2.0.6.jar

amazon-kinesis-client-multilang-2.0.5.jar

amazon-kinesis-client-multilang-2.0.5-javadoc.jar

amazon-kinesis-client-multilang-2.0.5-sources.jar

amazon-kinesis-client-2.0.5.jar

amazon-kinesis-client-2.0.5-javadoc.jar

amazon-kinesis-client-2.0.5-sources.jar

I added those jar files in the Project[properties]-> Libraries  (per image)

[image]

However, the code is still either not picking up the dependency or contrary to other’s findings, the dependency to kinesis.clientlibrary.exceptions may not have been built from the AWS Kinesis Client library.

In case its important – the source code of the Kinesis Client Library in GitHub (which I’ve compiled) does not have a ClientLibrary file nor directory.

Any thoughts? Know of any Jar files I am missing? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If you search for `maven <whatever class>` then maven will tell you what library it is in

see

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.amazonaws/amazon-kinesis-client -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
    <artifactId>amazon-kinesis-client</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the reply.
After further investigation, Amazon upgraded their Kinesis Library.
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/streams/latest/dev/kcl-migration.html

Thus, the new implementation calls for the KCL 2.0 Interface.
For example, "com.amazonaws.services.kinesis.clientlibrary.interfaces.v2.IRecordProcessor" should be changed to software.amazon.kinesis.processor.ShardRecordProcessor....

Among several other calls, imports, and method changes that are listed in:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/streams/latest/dev/kcl-migration.html

Thanks